# Is it possible to log into jupyter running on local network and use all its features?

Tags: python, networking, localhost, jupyter-lab

Would it possible to run Jupyter lab or notebook which is installed on a different machine on local network? Something like 192.168.1.8:port_address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes of course you can. 
Start the the jupyter notebook with this:

```
jupyter notebook --ip <your_LAN_ip> --port 8888
```

Then visit:

```
http://your_LAN_ip:8888
```

from another computer.
You can easily change the port number 8888 to any number you want, for example 6006.

It's recommended that you use a password when accessing your notebook server. To set up a password, just run jupyter notebook password. Otherwise, someone can access to your notebook.

Here is the link for setting notebook's password: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#notebook-server-security